# Order list of lists by length of second element in sublist python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, variables

Let's say I have the following list of lists

```
lst=[[['A'],[3,4,5,6]],[['B'],[3,4,5,6,5,7,8,9]],[['C'],[3,4]]]
```

I need to order the list by the length of the second element, in ascending order. Thus, the final result would be:

```
Result=[[['C'],[3,4]],[['A'],[3,4,5,6]],[['B'],[3,4,5,6,5,7,8,9]]]
```

I know that via this .sort() I can sort elements by length, but it only works if the list of lists is composed of 1 element.

```
sorted(lst, key = len)
```

How could I sort it by the length of the second element?

Comment: ```lst.sort(key = lambda x: len(x[1]))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
sorted(lst, key = lambda x: len(x[1]))
```

```
lst=[[['A'],[3,4,5,6]],[['B'],[3,4,5,6,5,7,8,9]],[['C'],[3,4]]]


Result=[[['C'],[3,4]],[['A'],[3,4,5,6]],[['B'],[3,4,5,6,5,7,8,9]]]

print(Result == sorted(lst, key = lambda x: len(x[1])))
```

```
True
```

for every item in the list

```
[['C'],[3,4]],[['A'],[3,4,5,6]],[['B'],[3,4,5,6,5,7,8,9]]
```

we take len(x[1])

```
[['C'],[3,4]] #item
[3,4] # x[1]
```

and finally, sort by that.

Answer (score 5):

`lst.sort(key = lambda x : len(x[1]))`